# How does read from firebase works?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So for example, I fetched 100 collection from Firestore.

If I console.log the data from Firestore twice, does it still read as 100 or 200?

Comment: I'm not clear what you're measuring.  Do you mean that you're fetching 100 *documents* from a collection in Firestore?  What is the code that performs the query and its logging?  Please edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A document read is charged when the document is read on the server on your behalf.

So:

- When you read a document snapshot from the server to the client, you will be charged for that read.
- When you read a document snapshot from the client's local cache, you won't be charged.
- When you call `data()` on a document snapshot you are not charged, so you can call it multiple times without getting charged.

So: loading a `DocumentSnapshot` may be charged, depending on whether it requires a read from/on the server. Subsequently calling `data()` on that snapshot is not a charged operation.